# Parallelize SVD computations c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, svd, factorization

So I've would like to do an SVD factorization of a large matrix (1000-25000 x 4096) in C++. I have tried LAPACKE dgesdd, Armadillo svd/svd_econ and Eigen but all of them seem to be single threaded and quite slow. I'm also currently trying to implement a solution based on redsvd.

Do you have any suggestions on how to implement a fast SVD factorization preferably using multi-threading. I've noticed that Matlab is using multi-threaded SVD so it should be possible.

Also, I'm running g++ on a 64-bit Linux machine if that would be of any importance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using CUDA and do it on GPU.

Answer (score 3):

Intel's Math Kernel Libraries offer parallel implementations of LAPACKE. They are available for Linux as well.

Comment: You can also install [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/), and then re-install [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net) to make use of it.  This should give you multi-threaded SVD.